# Data reduction/transformation

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, size-reduction

Has anyone seen any method to reduce the data for reducing the computation amount? What I mean by that is when number of features are huge, one may apply PCA to reduce the dimension and computation. What if we have a handful of features but huge number of data points (time series).
 How can one reduce that?

Comment: You could do that by downsampling the data

Answer (score 0):

Subsampling is fairly common.

Many statistical properties are well preserved when you subsample. If you have 1000000 points, the mean estimated from just 10000 is already very close; and maybe well within the reliability of your data.

Another approach is clustering with a simple and fast method such as k-means - and a large k, say sqrt(N). This will approximate your data with a least-squares objective using k data points. (You should also use the *weights* afterwards, as the resulting vectors will reflect different amounts of data).

Last but not least, many reduction techniques - probably including PCA - can be used on the *transposed* matrix. Then you reduce the number of instances, not the number of variables. But PCA is fairly expensive and on the transposed matrix, it would scale O(n³). So I would rather consider directly working with a truncated SVD.

But apparently your data are time series. I would suggest to look for data reduction that integrates your knowledge about what is important here.